# How to replace all last html elements tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all last element tags in a string.

So var I have this

```
lastTagRegex = /(<([^>]+)>)($)/; 
selection = container.innerHTML.replace(lastTagRegex, "")
```

It works for scenarios like this

```
<span>blah blah</span>
```

I get exactly what I need, which is `<span>blah blah`

But then there are scenarios like these

```
<p><span>blah blah</span></p>
<body><p><span>blah blah</span></p></body>
```

I need all the above tag endings removed

```
<p><span>blah blah</span></p>
<body><p><span>blah blah</span></p></body>
```

**But I don't want ALL tag endings removed!** For example, the `</span>` shouldn't be removed in the following case

```
<p><span>blah blah</span> blah blah</p>
```

Comment: I think you need to update your input string and output string. They're the same after `replacing/removing`.

Comment: @Tân I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I added a * in your regexp `(<([^>]+)>)*($)`

Comment: @Simon, yes! Thank you. Convert it into an answer and I'll except it

Comment: You are welcome  and I'd rather just leave it. Recently I've been criticized that I should not use regexp to do HTML parsing works, I was afraid your question is a bait for downvoting my answers, LOL.

Comment: LOL @Simon - It is not only that, but the question seems to be an X/Y question. I would need to know WHY relidon needs to remove the end tags before I would even start answering

Comment: @mplungjan Whenever I ask questions here I try to not be long-winded. I had a different account here and I've asked some questions where I embarrassingly added more than needed. I thought to give the context of why I needed to remove the takes would be pointless.

Comment: It is never pointless. I do not know why you would have problems giving too much context unless it interfered with the answering. In this specific case, the reason for using regex might outweigh the reasons for never using regex when parsing HTML, but we do not know and cannot give you a possibly better answer unless we know:) I use DOM parsing exclusively when I need to parse HTML

Comment: @mplungjan I'll keep that in mind next time. Honestly, I thought this was better from the standpoint of those that are going to answer. But now I'm intrigued by how you would have handled my problem. I'm creating a highlighter extension, you highlight `<p>something <strong> here` what `getSelection(), brings back is ``<p>something <strong> here</strong><p>` and so I'm converting that to `<p><highlight>something</highlight><strong><highlight>here</highlight></strong>` I used regex to find all the tags, but I didn't know how to do what I asked

Comment: So you are highlighting a string of HTML? Otherwise how to highlight `<p>something <strong> here` and only get the <strong> and not the </strong>? I would certainly try to domparse that instead if I understood your question better. That is what [mcve] are for

Answer (score 0):

Pass second parameter of `replace` function that will check if it's span element:

```js
innerHtml = "<p><span>blah blah</span></p><body><p><span>blah blah</span></p></body>";

selection = innerHtml.replace(/<\/\w+>/g, function (match, contents) {
    console.log(match);
    if (match == '</span>') {
        return '</span>';
    } else {
         return '';
    }
});

alert(selection);
```